# Filter CSRF token to secure against CSRF

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4, csrf, csrf-protection

I am following this article http://blog.neoxia.com/laravel4-and-angularjs/ to set up and filter the CSRF token. 
I am able to make it working on local server but after I deployed live and tested it, I keep getting "status code 418". Any idea?

Below is my code:

Route.php:

```
// Route to filter CSRF
Route::filter('serviceCSRF',function(){
if (Session::token() != Request::header('csrf_token')) {
    return Response::json([
        'message' => 'Security token doesn\'t match, possible CSRF attack.'
    ], 418);
}
});

// Route for authentication
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/auth', 'after' => 'allowOrigin'], function() {

Route::get('check', [
    'as'=>'check_auth_path',
    'uses'=>'SessionsController@check'
]);

Route::post('login', [
    'as'=>'login_path',
    'uses'=>'SessionsController@login'
]);

Route::get('sentryLogout', [
    'as'=>'logout_path',
    'uses'=>'SessionsController@logout'
]);
});
```

Session Controller:

```
class SessionsController extends \BaseController {

public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('serviceCSRF');
}
...
```

app.js:

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", "//" + window.location.hostname + "/api/csrf", false);
xhReq.send(null);

app.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", xhReq.responseText);

app.run(function ($window, $couchPotato, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $http, CSRF_TOKEN) {
    app.lazy = $couchPotato;
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    // editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';

    $http.defaults.headers.common['csrf_token'] = CSRF_TOKEN;

    // watch for location path change
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart",function() {

    ....
```

Comment: erm guys, why all the down votes?

Comment: The statuscode is an april-fools joke...

Comment: I know that. The question is why it works on local but not on production?

Comment: You are downvoted because you dont supply your code, no desired result, and supply us with an error which is bogus...

Comment: @Richard: I am sorry, just edited and added my code.

Comment: I found out request header: Request::header('csrf_token') returns null. Does this means it does not return the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The reason is that Request::header(); unable to interpret the parameter with underscore(csrf_token). So after I changed to

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['csrfToken'] = CSRF_TOKEN;
```

and it works!

Thanks to rvs1977 from (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1655#issuecomment-20595277)